# Keras Bidirectional "RuntimeError: You must compile your model before using it." after compilation completed

Tags: python-3.x, keras

I'm trying to create a small Bidirectional recurrent NN. The model itself compiles without error, but when trying to fit the model I get the error stating I should compile first. Please see the code snippet below:

```
# fourth recurrent model, bidirectional
bidirectional_recurrent = Sequential()
bidirectional_recurrent.add(Bidirectional(GRU(32, input_shape=(int(lookback/steps), data_scaled.shape[-1]))))
bidirectional_recurrent.add(Dense(1))

bidirectional_recurrent.compile(optimizer='rmsprop', loss='mae')

bidirectional_recurrent_history = bidirectional_recurrent.fit_generator(train_gen, steps_per_epoch=500, epochs=40,
                                               validation_data=val_gen, validation_steps=val_steps)
```

RuntimeError: You must compile your model before using it.

I've used the same setup to train unidirectional RNN's which worked fine. Any tips to help solve the run-time error are appreciated. (restarting the kernel did not help)
Maybe I did not instantiate 'Bidirectional' correctly?

Please note: This question is different from [Do I need to compile before 'X'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46127625/need-to-compile-keras-model-before-model-evaluate) type of questions
Note2: R examples of the same code can be found [here](https://tensorflow.rstudio.com/blog/time-series-forecasting-with-recurrent-neural-networks.html)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Found it,
When using Bidirectional, it should be treated as a layer, shifting the input_shape to be contained in Bidirectional() instead of in the GRU() object solved the problem

so

```
bidirectional_recurrent.add(Bidirectional(GRU(32, input_shape=(int(lookback/steps),
                            data_scaled.shape[-1]))))
```

becomes

```
bidirectional_recurrent.add(Bidirectional(GRU(32), input_shape=(int(lookback/steps),
                            data_scaled.shape[-1])))
```